# Meteor Facebook login with a signed request

Tags: facebook, meteor

My app uses Account-Facebook to handle Facebook login.

I'm trying to implement this way of login. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-login-with-games#login

Assuming I have for a particular user:

```
{
   "oauth_token": "{user-access-token}",
   "algorithm": "HMAC-SHA256",
   "expires": 1291840400,
   "issued_at": 1291836800,
   "user_id": "218471"
}
```

How can I hack Account-Facebook to log the user like Meteor.loginWithFacebook does?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I implemented :

**client/landing.html**

```
<template name="landing"> 
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="login" role="button">Login with Facebook</a>
</template>
```

**client/landing.js**

```
Template.landing.events({
    'click #login': function (e, tmpl) {
        console.log("Logging you in ");
        Meteor.loginWithFacebook({
            requestPermisssions: ['user']
        }, function(err){
            if(err){
                //handle errors
            }
            else{
                //show an alert
            }

       });
    } 
});
```

**server/accounts.js**

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(option, user){
    var accessToken = user.services.facebook.accessToken;
    var result, profile;
    result = Meteor.http.get("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me?fields=id,name,email,age_range",{
        params: {
            access_token: accessToken
        }       
    });

    if(result.error)
        throw result.error;

    fbData = _.pick(result.data,
        "name",
        "email",
        "age_range",
    )

    console.log(profile);
    return profile;
});
```

**server/config.js**

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
    service: "facebook"
});

ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
    service: "facebook",
    appId: "<your AppId>",
    secret: "<your App Secret>",
    loginStyle: "popup"
});
```

Have a look at [this](https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-customizing-login) tutorial.

Also you'll need to add this package : service-configuration

Comment: What I'm looking for is how to log the user automatically knowing his acess-token ie without Meteor.loginwithFacebook method.

Comment: I think you should not be able to do so. Else it will allow every app owner to log in any of its user, and in other tab open his facebook page.